# How can I connect to to my OpenVPN server with .ovpn file in electron js?

Tags: electron, openvpn

I have an `.ovpn` config file with a built-in username and password that was uploaded to a server through my API. While I obtained this file via the API, I now need to use it in conjunction with a username and password entered into text fields. My goal is to utilize all of this information to establish a connection to my OpenVPN server using Electron.js. Is there a way to achieve this?

I use the following code, but it doesn't work:

```js
const electron = require('electron')
var openvpnmanager = require('node-openvpn')

var opts = {
    host: 'my server ip address', // normally '127.0.0.1', will default to if undefined
    port: my server port, //port openvpn management console
    timeout: 60000, //timeout for connection - optional, will default to 1500ms if undefined
    config: 'http://mydomain/configs/client.ovpn'
};
var auth = {
    user: 'user@gmail.com',
    pass: 'secret'
};

var openvpn = openvpnmanager.connect(opts)

openvpn.on('connected', () => {
    openvpnmanager.authorize(auth);
});

// emits console output of openvpn instance as a string
openvpn.on('console-output', output => {
    console.log(output)
});

// emits console output of openvpn state as a array
openvpn.on('state-change', state => {
    console.log(state)
});

// emits console output of openvpn state as a string
openvpn.on('error', error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work.  Is node-openvpn working fine as a standalone node script for you, on the same machine?